# Regular expression to cut email address after "@"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

Let's say that...

```
<%= @user.email %>
```

produces

```
john@microsoft.com
```

How do you cut all characters after the "@" so it becomes...

```
john
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001192):

```
s.sub(/@.*/, '')
```

Or match all the characters before the at-sign:

```
/^(.*?)@/
```

Comment: Thank you all! Sometimes I feel sad using StackOverflow, because you people are so helpful, but I can't mark you all as correct answer :( I flipped a coin and it choose this answer..

Answer (score 8):

You could use [`split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001165):

```
str = "john@example.com"
parts = str.split("@")
puts parts[0] //john
```

Example: http://ideone.com/0mSID

Answer (score 2):

An `@`, followed by any number of any characters, to the end.

```
result = subject.gsub(/@.*$/, "").
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[^@]+
```

meaning: any character any number of times but NOT the @